# 'It' vs 'this' difference

Tags: grammar

Which one is more correct in the following context: '**it**' or '**this**' ?

> John‚ have you heard that the government has decided to cut fifty four thousand trees for a new project? Is [**it / this**] a correct decision? What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

> Is [it / this] a correct decision?

In order of preference:

1. Do you think that's the right decision?
2. Is that a good decision?
3. Is that a good idea?
4. Do you think what they are doing is a good idea?
5. Is this a good idea?

Just from my perspective, the choice of the word "it" sounds slightly like a foreign person is talking.